# How to enable admins/editors to set a featured image for specific category?

Tags: categories, post-thumbnails

Well , I know how to set up a featured image for a post . But I want to set up a featured image for categories . So  admins/editors can choose a featured image ,like they do for posts .

And one more thing , I want to show list of categories in home page instead of showing posts or something static .

Thanks in advance

Comment: I do not want to use a plugin ,instead of using plugin I want to modify function.php file

Comment: I recently tried to accomplish this and found that the most user friendly way to accomplish this is a [plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/categories-images/). Otherwise you have to somehow incorporate the media library which is a whole other can of worms.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a image URL custom field: http://wpcrumbs.com/2013/09/how-to-add-custom-fields-to-categories/

Comment: Please explain why this is helpful. Also move in the important bits of code that are necessary to solve the question. [Link only answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) will die when the links die (link rot) and are automatically flagged by the community bot as "low quality" and open for deletion.